# Count the number of employees for every country

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this task:

*Count the number of employees for every country. Show only those countries, when works more than 20 employees*

- employee_id is dedicated for **Employees table**
- country belongs to different table - **Countries table** and we need country_name from this table

I have no idea how to solve this task. Below what I was able to create. I think we should use Inner Join.

```
SELECT a.employee_id
    , b.country_name
    , COUNT(a.employee_id) AS count
FROM   employees a
      INNER JOIN countries b ON a.employee_id = b.country_name
GROUP BY b.country_name
WHERE employee_id >20;
```

I think I need help from the beginning. 
Thanks

Comment: Almost. If you think about it what does a.employee_id give you here? You don't need that in your select. Also, `count employee_id > 20` isn't the same as `count(a.employee_id) > 20`. I'd rather not just give you the answer because I feel you are close enough that figuring it out would be of more benefit to you

Answer (score 0):

Your join doesn't seem correct but as I don't know the table structure, I can't say what the right column is (I'm going to assume that it should be **country_name**. Even so, try this:

```
SELECT b.country_name
    , COUNT(a.employee_id) AS count
FROM   employees a
      INNER JOIN countries b ON a.country_name = b.country_name
GROUP BY b.country_name
HAVING COUNT(employee_id) >20;
```

When grouping you need to use the HAVING statement to filter.